# R plotly x-axis use labels for display

Tags: r, plotly, axis-labels, x-axis

Trying to use R Plotly to graph bar chart.  I need the chart x-axis ordered by q_order but need to have the x-axis display the labels from data called title. How would I do this?

Data

[image]

Chart

[image]

Code

```
 fig <- plot_ly(
  data = ybq,
  x = ~q_order,
  y = ~t_put,
  type = "bar"
) %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(
               autorange="reversed", 
               type="category"
               ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can arrange the factor levels for `title` based on values in `q_order`.

```
library(plotly)

ybq$title <- factor(ybq$title, ybq$title[order(ybq$q_order)])

plot_ly(
  data = ybq,
  x = ~title,
  y = ~q_order,
  type = "bar"
)
```

[image]

**data**

```
ybq <- data.frame(title = c('21-Jan', 'Q4 2020', 'Q3 2020', 'Q2 2020'), 
                  t_put = c(1606, 11419, 10882, 6525), 
                  q_order = c(112021, 42020,32020, 22020))
```

Comment: I was trying to use reorder instead of the method you mentioned.  Thank you!